# Excel VBA to open a workbook and switch to a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon. I am currently very novice a VBA and am trying to create a simple code that will open a workbook, flip to a specific worksheet (Transaction Analysis) and run two macros. Then is should flip to worksheet "Fund Trend" and run those same two macros, then save and close. I found this code online and have slightly modified to try to open a specific sheet within the workbook with no luck.

If I exclude the line regarding "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Analysis") then the script works correctly for the open worksheet. It is when I try to add anything referencing a specific worksheet within the workbook that I run into issues. The the script shown below, the workbook opens and that's it. The script stops there and does not run the macros.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions! The idea is to schedule schedule the execution of the final vbscript with task scheduler. Thank You!

```
Dim args, objExcel

Set args = wscript.Arguments
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.workbooks.open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Analysis")

objExcel.Run "Clear"

objExcel.Run "SecurityDistribution"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: No Luck doesn't tell us what is happening...be more specific about what you expect and what is occurring.   Also as an FYI, You need to enable access to the VBA Project model in Options>>Trust Center Settings>>Macros

Comment: Try ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Analysis").Activate

Comment: Thank You. My comment has been updated with more information.

Comment: I've also tried ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Transaction Analysis").Activate and at this point, the workbook opens, but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Is there any error or something. Or it just stops?

Comment: It just stops. No errors that I can tell. The workbook opens to the worksheet that was open when last saved and that's where it stops.

Comment: did you try fully qualifying the worksheet via the workbook object. objExcel.Sheets("Transaction Analysis").Activate

Comment: fully qualifying the worksheet via the workbook allowed the macros to finish successfully. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying to want to run a Macro in another Workbook other than the one that has focus?  If that's all it is, try this one-liner.

Application.Run "MacroBook!MacroName"

Notice, you don't need to select a specific Worksheet to run a Macro.  You do, however, need to select the right Workbook!